# IntelliJ IDEA Bug Life Cycle Overview

Tags: intellij-idea, lifecycle, bug-tracking, states, bug-reporting

Under the IDEA Bug Repo
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA you can find 15 different states:

- Submitted
- Open
- In Progress
- To be discussed
- Wait for Reply
- Reopened
- Can't Reproduce
- Duplicate
- Fixed
- Declined
- Incomplete
- Obsolete
- Works As Intended
- Answered
- Third Party Problem

I can only find some information here

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.4/resolve-issues.html#resolve-issues-multiple-state-type-fields

and here
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.4/Default-Custom-Fields.html

about it.

But unfortunately I can't find some information about a definition/description of each state.

Is there a Overview about the life cycle, state description and state transitions?

I'm looking for something like this:
https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: I do not think such document exists. Why is it needed and what would you exactly want to know?

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I write a paper about Bug-Reports